# Why not use TryTakeFromAny instead of TakeFromAny

Tags: c#, blockingcollection

So I am just learning about Pipelines, and was wondering when you would have a case where you WANT to use [`TakeFromAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.takefromany) instead of [`TryTakeFromAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.trytakefromany). `TryTakeFromAny` seems to be a lot safer to use, rather than getting a hard exit which can cause issues whenever `TakeFromAny` has no items to take out of the `BlockingCollection`.